# Javascript scroll doesn't stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

hi everyone i'm trying to do simple scroll share box widget but it doesn't work. It must stop on special div (stopscroll), but it don't stop and scrolling down until web page footer. any ideas why?

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw),
        $bumper = $(elem),
        bumperPos = $bumper.offset().top,
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight(),
        setPosition = function(){
            if ($window.scrollTop() <= (bumperPos - thisHeight)) {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: (bumperPos - thisHeight)
                });
            } else {
                $this.css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    top: 0
                });
            }
        };
    $window.resize(function()
    {
        bumperPos = pos.offset().top;
        thisHeight = $this.outerHeight();
        setPosition();
    });
    $window.scroll(setPosition);
    setPosition();
};

$('#share_box').followTo('#stopscroll');
```

but it doesn't stop on the div #stopscroll.

css file looks like that:

```
#share_box{
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #E1E1E1;
position: fixed;
width: 65px;
padding: 15px;
border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
left: 1.89%;}
```

any ideas?
here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NCY6x/

Comment: Did you add jQuery? (It's not in your jsfiddle)

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of syntax and variable mistakes in your code...

I have updated the fiddle with a working and simpler demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NCY6x/2/

```
$.fn.followTo = function ( elem ) {
    var stopper = $(elem);
    var box = this;
    $(window).on("scroll resize", function(){
        var x_distance = (stopper.offset().top- box.outerHeight());
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= x_distance){
            box.css({"position": "absolute", "top": x_distance});
        } else {
            box.css({"position": "fixed", "top": 0});
        }
    });
};

$('#share_box').followTo('#stopscroll');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your Fiddle you haven't actually loaded `jQuery`, and then when loaded I get an error saying `pos is not defined`, which I think refers to the following line:

`bumperPos = pos.offset().top;`

`pos` doesn't appear to be set anywhere

Edit:

There were some other issues with your script. See here for a version that I think works as you intend http://jsfiddle.net/R5z6j/1/

I removed the padding on the top of `#stopscroll` as that doesn't move the element down so the top position was always being set to 18px (see the console output)

Edit 2:

http://jsfiddle.net/R5z6j/5/ - as you'll probably actually want it this way round

Comment: I think the poster is looking to do the opposite of what you have done. Have it so that the "THIS IS SCROOOOOOLLLL" box scrolls with the page from the top, until you get to a certain point where it will stick.

Comment: Matthew u are right! here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/R5z6j/2/ . i want to scroll stop on certain div

Comment: Was going to say, that's easy enough, just swap the CSS sections around and you have it. Update the answer with this

Comment: i try everything, to fiddle it's working but not on my website. here is fiddle what actually 1:1 like my site http://jsfiddle.net/A2GC5/ thanks for helping!

Comment: Once again, you've not set the Fiddle to load jQuery. Does your site have jQuery? Can you post a link to it?

Comment: yes i loaded jQuery on my website. here is web page source: <script src="/themes/admin/js/jquery-ui-1.8.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

Comment: i think the problem is jquery UI:   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/themes/admin/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.min.js"></script> what u think about it?